# Careers onebox seems outdated

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, chat, onebox

Afaik, "Careers 2.0" is the old name for Careers.SO, and there is no logo where it usually is in oneboxes, just text. So the logo is not working and all instances of "Careers 2.0" should probably read something like "Careers StackOverflow" instead.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great catch! The job posting one box now shows "Stack Overflow Careers", not "Careers 2.0".

As a sidenote/funfact, you're currently seeing "Careers 2.0" on the left because it's the alt text for the logo, which an adblocker or something is blocking. However, the logo that we showed there when the company themselves didn't have one provided was out of date too so that will be updated as of the next Careers prod push (sometime later today).

Here's what it all looks like now:

[image]